# Различные типы функций

Tags: c++, типы

Не очень понимаю, почему следующий код выводит `0 1 0`. Какие типы у `foo_1`, `foo_2` и `foo_3`?

```
void foo() {}

int main() {
    using foo_1 = decltype(foo);
    using foo_2 = const foo_1&;
    using foo_3 = foo_1&;


    std::cout << std::is_same_v<foo_1, foo_2> << '\n'
              << std::is_same_v<foo_2, foo_3> << '\n'
              << std::is_same_v<foo_1, foo_3> << '\n';
}
```

Тем более на `gcc` следующий код даёт одинаковые значения

```
std::cout << typeid(foo_1).name() << '\n'
          << typeid(foo_2).name() << '\n'
          << typeid(foo_3).name() << '\n';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo_2` и `foo_3` являются ссылками на функцию (причём `const` для `foo_2` проигнорирован и эти типы вообще полностью идентичны). В то время как `foo_1` тип - функция (не указатель на функцию). Поэтому и получается такой результат в `std::is_same_v`. [Несколько примеров](https://wandbox.org/permlink/v77dBdxHWnx0rjbb):

```
#include <iostream>

void f() {}

int main() 
{
    using F = decltype(f); // тип функции
    using FR = void(&)();  // тип ссылки на функцию
    using FP = void(*)();  // тип указателя на функцию (using форма)
    typedef void (*FP2)(); // тип указателя на функцию (typedef форма)

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<F, void()> << "\n";     // true  (F - функция)
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<F, FR> << "\n";         // false (F - не ссылка на функцию)
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<F, FP> << "\n";         // false (F - не указатель на функцию)
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<FP, FP2> << "\n";       // true  (FP и FP2 одно и то же, заданное разными способами)
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<F&, FR> << "\n";        // true  (F& - ссылка на функцию)
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<const FR, FR> << "\n";  // true  (const не влияет на тип ссылки на функцию)
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<const F, F> << "\n";    // true  (const не влияет на тип функции)    
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<const FP, FP> << "\n";  // false (const влияет на тип указателя на функцию)    
}
```

При этом `typeid(/* */).name()` даёт одинаковые результаты потому, что для ссылок и значений он работает единообразно, можете попробовать например `typeid(int&).name()` и  `typeid(int).name()`. А учитывая неявные преобразования между типом функции и типом указателя на функцию одинаковость результата здесь тоже не вызывает особых вопросов.

Comment: А почему игнорируется `const`?

Comment: @egor, потому что `const` это модификатор типа, а `typeid` возвращает информацию по типу. Ни ссылка ни `const` не являются самостоятельными типами, поэтому его поведение вполне логично.

Comment: @ixSci я имею в виду, почему `foo_2` и `foo_3` - одинаковые? почему `const` в `foo_2` не учитывается?

Comment: @egor потому что для типа функции это не имеет смысла. [Пример в черновике стандарта](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#7).

Comment: "const не влияет на тип ссылки на функцию". Верно, но немного сбивает с толку. Внешний const не влияет на тип вообще никаких ссылок. То, что это ссылка на функцию, роли не играет.

Comment: @AnT ну да. [Приколы синонимизации](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bNKYjIPWWGzJwm2T), работает не так, как ожидают многие. [Пример из стандарта](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec#3) для указателя, но смысл тот же.

Answer (score 0):

Тип `foo` - `void (void)`, `foo_2` и `foo_3` - `void ( & ) (void)`. `const` в этом контексте ничего не делает (`warning: 'const' qualifier on function type 'foo_1' (aka 'void ()') has no effect [-Wignored-qualifiers]`)

`typeid` выдает одинаковые результаты потому что не различает ссылок.